# Absolute continuity of function

Tags: calculus

I understand uniform continuity of a function. The function just can't grow too fast. But what about absolute continuity? Is there any good explanation of it? I understand definition, but I don't get the concept of it.

Comment: Operational meaning of absolute continuity = fundamental theorem of calculus does apply (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), although in a somewhat extended sense - absolute continuity implies almost everywhere differentiability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity. In the context of probability theory, when the distribution function of a random variable is absolutely continuous, then the random variable admits a density.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of *absolute continuity* allows to modelize functions that does not "oscillate" too much on a given interval. Consider, for example, the function $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$ defined in zero as $f(0)=0$: this is continuous, but not absolutely continuous (for example, on $[-1,1]$ or $[0,1]$).

Just a clarification on *continuity*: this notion doesn't actually give you an absolute control on the growth of a function, but it tells you that you can control the increment of your function (the $\epsilon$ in the definition) taking a small increment of your variable (the $\delta$). The global growth of your function can be actually fast.
Please, notice that the increment of the variable, $\delta$, depends on the point of continuity (at least, in general).